# if statement getElementById.src

Tags: javascript, php, html

SOLVED

```
 var player = 0;
 if(player == 0)
{
    document.getElementById("sp").src = "../image/start.png";
    player = 1;
}
else if(player == 1)
{
    document.getElementById("sp").src = "../image/stop.png";
    player = 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make play/pause button in JavaScript.
The first text only version works fine using `innerHtml` but I need to use an image file for the final version.

I got 3 folders in my root dir:

- `image` (where the image files are)
- `slide` (where the php file are)
- `javascript` (where the js file is placed)

In my php file:

```
<img src="../image/stop.png" id="sp">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/page1.js"></script>
```

In my js file:

```
if(document.getElementById("sp").src == "../image/stop.png") {
    document.getElementById("sp").src = "../image/start.png";
} else if(document.getElementById("sp").src == "../image/start.png") {
    document.getElementById("sp").src = "../image/stop.png";
}
```

I have search for a sulotion to this but I can't get it to work.

The old code for the text verison looks like this.

```
if(document.getElementById("sp").innerHTML == "Stop") {
    document.getElementById("sp").innerHTML = "Start";
} else if(document.getElementById("sp").innerHTML == "Start") {
    document.getElementById("sp").innerHTML = "Stop";
}
```

The code is in a function triggerd on an click event

Can someone please help me get this to work?

Here is the whloe js code.
I know this may not be optmal written but I'm very new to js

```
var CB = 
{
addEvent : function(element, event, action)
{
    if (element.addEventListener){
        element.addEventListener(event, action, false);
    }
    else
    {
        element.attachEvent("on" + event, action);
    }
}
 }

 Timer = function(callback, delay) 
 {
     var timerId, start, remaining = delay;
   this.pause = function() 
 {
  window.clearTimeout(timerId);
  remaining -= new Date() - start;
  };
  this.resume = function()
  {
  start = new Date();
  timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
   };
   this.resume();
   };

  var synlig = 0.0;

  function visa(pic)
  {
synlig += 0.1;
if(synlig < 1.0)
{
    var x = String(synlig)
       pic.style.opacity = x;
}
else
{
     pic.style.opacity="1.0";
     return;
}
setTimeout(function(){visa(pic)}, 120);
   }

var     ejSynlig = 1.0
 function visaEJ(pic)
  {
ejSynlig -= 0.1;
if(ejSynlig > 0.0)
{
    var x = String(ejSynlig)
       pic.style.opacity = x;
}
else
{
     pic.style.opacity="0.0";
     return;
}
setTimeout(function(){visaEJ(pic)}, 120);
    }

  var   synlig2 = 0.0;
  function visa2(pic2)
  {
synlig2 += 0.1;
if(synlig2 < 1.0)
{
    var x = String(synlig2)
    pic2.style.opacity = x;
}
else
{
     pic2.style.opacity="1.0";
     return;
}
setTimeout(function(){visa2(pic2)}, 120);
    }

     var    ejSynlig2 = 1.0
     function visaEJ2(pic2)
    {
ejSynlig2 -= 0.1;
if(ejSynlig2 > 0.0)
{
    var x = String(ejSynlig2)
    pic2.style.opacity = x;
}
else
{
     pic2.style.opacity="0.0";
     return;
}
setTimeout(function(){visaEJ2(pic2)}, 120);
    }

  var pic = document.getElementById("bild");
   var t1s = new Timer(function(){visa(pic)}, 5000);
  var t1h = new Timer(function(){visaEJ(pic)}, 11000);
  var pic2 = document.getElementById("bild2");
 var t2s = new Timer(function(){visa2(pic2)}, 11500);
 var t2h = new Timer(function(){visaEJ2(pic2)}, 15000);

 function imgs()
 {
var p = document.getElementById("sp");
var x1, y1, x2, y2;

if(document.getElementById("sp").src == "../image/stop.png")
{
    x1 = t1s.pause();
    y1 = t1h.pause();
    x2 = t2s.pause();
    y2 = t2h.pause();
}   
else if(document.getElementById("sp").src == "../image/start.png")
{
    x1 = t1s.resume();
    y1 = t1h.resume();
    x2 = t2s.resume();
    y2 = t2h.resume();
}
CB.addEvent(p, "click", x1);
CB.addEvent(p, "click", y1);
CB.addEvent(p, "click", x2);
CB.addEvent(p, "click", y2);
 }

 function snd()
 {
var sndP = document.getElementById("sndP");
function playS()
{
    sndP.volume = 0.5;
    sndP.play();
} 
function pauseS()
{
    sndP.pause();
} 
var p = document.getElementById("sp");
var y;
if(document.getElementById("sp").src == "../image/stop.png")
{
    y = pauseS();
}
else if(document.getElementById("sp").src == "../image/start.png")
{
    y = playS();
}
CB.addEvent(p, "click", y);
 }

 function theshit()
 {
imgs();
snd();
if(document.getElementById("sp").src == "../image/stop.png")
{
    document.getElementById("sp").src = "../image/start.png";
}
else if(document.getElementById("sp").src == "../image/start.png")
{
    document.getElementById("sp").src = "../image/stop.png";
}
 }

 var sp = document.getElementById("sp");
 CB.addEvent(sp, "click", theshit);  
 sndP.volume = 0.5;
 sndP.play();
```

Comment: Why don't you have a stop AND a start button and show/hide those? You could even use CSS and apply something like a 'is-playing` class and hide them conditionally.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(document.getElementById("sp").src == "../image/stop.png")
{
    document.getElementById("sp").setAttribute("src","../image/start.png");
}
else if(document.getElementById("sp").src == "../image/start.png")
{
    document.getElementById("sp").setAttribute("src","../image/stop.png");
}
```

Comment: still not getting?

use <input type='image' > instead of <img>

Answer (score 0):

So you want to toggle the image when clicked?

if you set something to `src` and then get it, it might look a little bit different.
a better solution, than to check if something has a specific url, you could save the `isPlaying` variable manually. this way you would `writeonly` to the DOM, which is faster, then reading the `src` value manually all the time.

```
var isPlaying = false;
var stopImg = "../images/stop.png";
var playImg = "../images/start.png";
var el = document.getElementById("sp");

$("button").click(function() {

    // toggle 
    el.src = isPlaying ? stopImg : playImg;
    // also toggle the var
    isPlaying = !isPlaying;

});
```

even a better way is to do it using CSS and for example a background-image...

```
button {
    /*default state*/
    background-image : url('/images/play.png');
}

button.isPlaying {
    /*state when playing*/
    background-image : url('/images/stop.png');
}
```

and then in JS

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("isPlaying");
});
```

Comment: It's not just to toggle the image i think ther is somthing wrong in the if statement becouse i check that if statement on other functions and non of them are working

Comment: yeah, as i said, dont check the `src` attribute for a specific value. there are nicer ways. like setting the `class` attribute. you also could set a `data` attribute. browsers sometimes change internally the URI to absolutes, if you set a relative

Comment: sorry but i have no time to read that ugly code, it is completely not understandable. you need to refactor this...

Comment: You should probably also mention that your solution relies on (presumably) jQuery being included.

Comment: @oGeez im using jQuery just something like a prototyping tool or pseudo code, as it takes longer attach correctly an event handler cross browser in vanilla js. I hoped he would understand what I **mean**. I did not intend to make the whole work for him :)

Comment: hey @user3636368, seems like the toggling using a variable helped? glad it **solved** your problem ?